# Register custom qgsfunction in pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-custom-function

I'm using pyqgis within an standalone application.
Now I wanted to create a custom expression to to use as filterExpression in rule of `ruleBasedRendererV2`. (I tried the renderer with existing functions before and everything worked fine!)

Custom `qgisfunction` (bitwise AND-function - as there is not such a function yet) looks like this:

```
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def bitwise_and(value1, value2, feature, parent):
    return value1 & value2
```

I also tried to register it, via:

```
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
QgsExpression.registerFunction(bitwise_and)
```

Testing the expression via:

```
expressionString = 'bitwise_and(2, 2) = 2'
exp = QgsExpression(expressionString)
if exp.hasParserError():
    print(exp.parserErrorString())
```

(Giving `2=2` so always `True`) works after registering function, and fails if not. But still, I can not use the expression within a rule...

Right now, the file containing the function lies on top in my project folder, which is automatically included to PATH, isn't it?! (According to Nathan Woodrow, file can be placed anywhere in PATH - see https://nathanw.net/2012/11/10/user-defined-expression-functions-for-qgis/).

**UPDATE:** Registering of function works so far, with code from above - now the problem lies in function itself...

**UPDATE #2:**

Very strange!
Simple function `do_nothing` getting two arguments works fine in my code:

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def do_nothing(value1, value2, feature, parent):
    return value1
```

Using expression `expString = 'do_nothing(2, 2) = 2'`

**UPDATE #3:**

Simple change of `do_nothing` to `add_one` does not work any longer:

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def add_one(value1, value2, feature, parent):
    return value1 + 1
```

calling it via `expString = 'add_one(2, 2) = 3'`.
That's why I think it has something to do with returning type?!

Comment: Copy your file in `~/.qgis2/python/expressions/` then reload QGIS and the function is available in the expression builder section python

Comment: Following your advice, function appears in QGIS function editor and I can use it as expected. But when trying to use it in my standalone application, function does not work! - I think, when QGIS starts, it somehow registers all files in expression folder, but I wonder how?!

Comment: Are you using the `@qgsfunction` function in your code, as in you define the function in code.  You can can ignore the `expressions` folder if you are making your own script that is just for the main app

Comment: You are right - when registering of the function works as described above (for example `do_nothing`). But my original function `bitwise_and` does still not work. Now, I think it has something to do with the return type of the function, since `do_nothing works`, but `add_one` does not!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally solved the problem!

It was really a type-problem, as input values are defined as `QVariant` inside `@qgsfunction`. So, to get my code work I had to convert them into integers first. Apparently, QGIS takes care of type conversions itself...

Function looks like this now:

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def bitwise_and(value1, value2, feature, parent):
    return value1.toInt()[0] & value2.toInt()[0]
```

And if you have the function placed in your project folder, don't forget to register it first:

```
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
QgsExpression.registerFunction(bitwise_and)
```